# the usage of dashes before relative pronouns

Tags: punctuation, writing-style, dashes

I came across these two sentences:

> 1. Today, his sculptures – **which** spin, tilt, and sway – belong to collections worldwide.
> 2. Today, his sculptures – spin, tilt, and sway – belong to collections worldwide.

Which one would be correct? Or would they both be acceptable?

Comment: You could omit *which* if you are talking about three sculptures, titled Spin, Tilt, and Sway.

Comment: Another question on EL&U asks about this same test prep question. See [ACT English question regarding dashes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/316002/act-english-question-regarding-dashes). There is actually some useful information in the comments (if I do say so myself), although both attempts at formal answers have been deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why the dashes G.B? There is nothing terribly wrong with sentence number one bereft of all dashes. Though it does contain a smattering of commas. Were it a sentence of my own i might grow two:

The sculptures spin, tilt, and sway. Today his art belongs to collections worldwide.